# Anúncios aleatórios com contador de visualizações

Tags: php, array, random, contador, números-aleatórios

Estou com o seguinte script para colocar anúncios aleatórios no site, além de simples e fácil também funciona muito bem e rápido com vários anúncios.

O problema é o seguinte:
Quantas vezes cada anúncio foi escolhido por esse script (quantas vezes eles foi visualizado)?

```
<?php
$imagens = array (
"http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/01.png",
"http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/02.png",
"http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/03.png"
);

$imagenstotal = count($imagens);
$imagenstotal--;
$randomimagens = rand(0,$imagenstotal);
$URL = array (

"http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/contato.php", // 01
"http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/contato.php", // 02
"http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br"              // 03
);

echo "<a href='$URL[$randomimagens]' target='_blank'>
<img style='border:1px solid #3f3f3f;' src='$imagens[$randomimagens]'> </a>";
?>
```

Comment: Se você usa algum banco de pode criar uma tabela com uma coluna com uma referencia e a outra com a quantidade e ir incrementando, se não tiver pode fazer um array da mesma forma serializar os dados e salvar em um txt.

Answer (score 1):

Podes guardar essa informação numa Base de Dados, esta solução não vai abranger isso, nesta vou focar-me em guardar essa informação num ficheiro, que é uma das maneiras de fazer isso:

```
<?php
$imagens = array (
    array(
        'img' => "http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/01.png",
        'url' => "http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/contato.php"
    ),
    array(
        'img' => "http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/02.png",
        'url' => "http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/contato.php"
    ),
    array(
        'img' => "http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/03.png",
        'url' => "http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br"
    ),
);
$img_rand = $imagens[rand(0, count($imagens) - 1)];

$ficheiro = 'tests.txt';
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents($ficheiro));

$num = 1;
foreach($lines as $key => $value) { // percorrer todas as linhas
    $img = explode(',', $value)[0];
    if($img == $img_rand['img']) { // caso a imagem já exista no ficheiro
        $num = explode(',', $value)[1] + 1; // vamos ver quantas vezes já apareceu e somar 1
        unset($lines[$key]); // apagar a linha antiga do nosso array
        break;
    }
}

$lines[] = $img_rand['img']. "," .$num; // acrescentar nova linha com o valor atualizado, seja pela primeira vez (1) ou não (quantidade anterior + 1)
$lines = implode("\n", $lines);
file_put_contents($ficheiro, trim($lines));

?>
<a href='<?php echo $img_rand['url'] ?>' target='_blank'>
<img style='border:1px solid #3f3f3f;' src='<?php echo $img_rand['img']; ?>'> </a>
```

Ajusta o nome do ficheiro onde queres guardar, este ficheiro vai ficar com a seguinte estrutura:

```
http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/03.png,16
http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/01.png,14
http://megafeiraoveiculos.com.br/banners/02.png,16
```

Como vemos a seguir à virgula está o número de vezes que a imagem calhou.

PS: É muito importante que não haja mais virgulas numa linha, apenas a que separa a imagem da quantidade de vezes que já apareceu

Espero que não te importes mas acho que melhorei um bocado a estrutura dos arrays `$imagens, $URL`, assim fica tudo junto numa mesma estrutura.

Comment: Miguel, teria alguma forma de bloquear a imagem para que ela não apareça mais de uma vez na mesma página? Pensei em usar cookie mas não sei se seria a opção certa. Vc pode entrar em contato comigo? ufrrj99@gmail.com